# html tables: unwanted gaps around images - Firefox (not Safari or Chrome)

Tags: css, firefox, responsive-design, html-table

I am creating a responsive HTML email so am using tables. I am testing as I go along in Firefox but cannot get rid of a thin gap that appears below an image when the CSS within the media queries kicks in. The background colour shows through between the tables. I have tried various fixes and include a stripped down example of my email below. The image is question is a curve cornered strip (body-copy-top-bdr.jpg) which sits above the content copy. The unwanted thin gap can be seen beneath this image when the viewport is 640px or lower.

Any helpful suggestions would be most welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>test table</title>                                                                                                      
<style type="text/css">


    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px)  {
                    body[yahoo] .deviceWidth {width:440px!important; padding:0 0px;}
                    body[yahoo] .imageWidth {width:400px!important; padding:0 0px;} 
                    body[yahoo] .center {text-align: center!important;}  
                    .twoColStack { width: 100%!important; display: block!important;}
                    .columnImage{ height:auto !important;}
                    .mobTab { display: block!important;}
                    .desk { display: none!important;}

                    body[yahoo] .deviceWidth img{display:block!important; line-height:0!important;}

            }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
                    body[yahoo] .deviceWidth {width:280px!important; padding:0 0px;}
                    body[yahoo] .imageWidth {width:250px!important; padding:0 0px;} 
                    body[yahoo] .center {text-align: center!important;}  
            }


</style>
</head>

<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" yahoo="fix" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse">
<!-- Wrapper -->
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0px" bgcolor="#000000" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse">
            <table width="580"  class="deviceWidth" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style=" padding-top:0px; padding-right:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left:0px;"><img  class="deviceWidth" src="images/body-copy-top-bdr.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="display: block;" /></td>
                </tr>        
            </table>            

            <!-- Row Two - Start One Column -->
            <table width="580"  class="deviceWidth" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse">                
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: 16px; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 20px; vertical-align: top; padding:10px 20px 10px 10px; border-spacing:0;" bgcolor="#ffffff">123456789</td>
                </tr>              
            </table>



        </td>
    </tr>
</table> <!-- End Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you tried giving "display: block" or "vertical-align: top" to img?

Comment: I already have 'display: block' in place and I have tried your suggestion of 'vertical-align: top' but that doesn't make any difference.